# NG2 Iterate through two API

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get working my script. It should iterate roster of players (JSON) where I get ID's.

Then I need to iterate players JSON. Where I get player details by roster ID's and then iterate and show players on frontend. It sounds very simple but for me it's kinda difficult.
Thanks for help!

service file

```
export class PlayersService {
    roster:any[];
    players:any[];

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.roster = [];
        this.players = [];
    }

    getPlayers() {
            for (let player of this.roster[0]["roster"]) {

                 this.http.get("PLAYERS JSON API,"+player['id_player'])
                    .do(val => this.players.push(val));
                 }   

         return this.players
    }


    getRoster() {
        return this.http.get("JSON ROSTER API GETS JSON WITH IDs")
       .map(res => res.json())
       .do(val => this.roster.push(val));
    }


}
```

component file

```
export class RosterPage extends Page implements OnInit {

    roster:any[];
    players:any[];

    constructor(private location: Location, private playersService: PlayersService) {
        super(location);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.playersService.getRoster().subscribe(val => this.playersService.getPlayers());


    }


}
```

Comment: you're not updating the component `players` from the service' `player` construct. You only call `this.playersService.getPlayers()` without assigning the result. Also, the result probably won't work either as-is since you miss merging the promises inside `getPlayers()`

Comment: Still I cant understand it. Could you send me real example pls?